# "callback contain no result Error: Error: base fee exceeds gas limit" when call selfdestruct function (using Remix IDE)

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, remix, selfdestruct

I'm testing this simple contract. All the functions works well, but when I call the `kill()` function I'm getting this error:

> callback contain no result Error: Error: base fee exceeds gas limit

I'm using Metamask (and testrpc).

Thanks in advance.
[image]

**EDIT**

I tried also with  [the greeter](https://www.ethereum.org/greeter) example , but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing the issue, but you don't need to declare the variable owner in Test since it inherits it from Owned.

Comment: Hi! I tried withouth the modifer onlyOwner, but have the same issue. Thanks the same for the clarification

Comment: Have you tried just increasing the gas limit field?  Sometimes remix can be wonky with stuff like that