# Buy tokens through the wallet

Tags: contract-development, ether, tokens

i deploy tokens in private net. If i deploy tokens in offical net, how people buy tokens? If they send ether on contract address, they will receives tokens?

For example function buy

```
function buy() payable {
    uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                // calculates the amount
    if (balanceOf[this] < amount) throw;               // checks if it has enough to sell
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;                   // adds the amount to buyer's balance
    balanceOf[this] -= amount;                         // subtracts amount from seller's balance
    Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                // execute an event reflecting the change
}
```

If have **payable**, people can buy tokens through the wallet, for example **myetherwallet**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, people can buy token through the wallet, for example MEW.

If you want to test locally:
first connect MEW to your local node, like testrpc (you can read more here ["Error: base fee exceeds gas limit" when using the withdrawal pattern](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22860/error-base-fee-exceeds-gas-limit-when-using-the-withdrawal-pattern/22915#22915));
then click tab `Contracts`, add your `Contract address` and `ABI/JSON interface`; finally, select the `buy` function, entering the amount of ETH you want to spend.

Hope this help.

Comment: I did, brought out: "invalid sender"

Comment: Yeah, work. I correctly understood that people through MEW will be able to buy without these actions, just seeing the address of the contract and quantity ETH with Gas?

Comment: I understand. Need create a unname function. Thank you