# Base fee exceeds gas limit on connecting to local instance of testrpc on Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, testrpc, contract-debugging

Note:
I have already visited the related [links](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/22860/error-base-fee-exceeds-gas-limit-when-using-the-withdrawal-pattern) which have similar questions posted, but I didn't find any solution which I could use to solve the issue Im facing.

Im following this [Coursetro tutorial](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-(Tutorial)), which basically guides those new to blockchain to create a simple smart contract.
The contract is defined as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Coursetro {

string fName;
uint age;

function setInstructor(string _fName, uint _age) public {
    fName = _fName;
    age = _age;
}

function getInstructor() public constant returns (string, uint) {
    return (fName, age);
}
}
```

However when I change the environment in the remix IDE from Javascript env to Web 3 env(To connect to the testrpc instance running locally on terminal), I get the following error:

```
creation of browser/Coursetro.sol:Coursetro pending...
creation of browser/Coursetro.sol:Coursetro errored: Error: base fee 
exceeds gas limit
at runCall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:70875:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:12643:24
at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:9736:17)
at iterateeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:9721:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:9696:16
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:12648:13
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:67073:16
at replenish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:67020:25)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:67029:9
at eachLimit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-
testrpc/build/cli.node.js:66953:36)
```

I understand that the fee for executing any contract must never exceed the Gas limit set, but in this case, Im unable to deduce where to set the Gas limit. Im new to this so kindly guide me as to how to solve the above error.

Comment: it's not working neither. I tried the testrpc -l 3000000 but in Remix still showing me the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: you need to initialize your account in Remix with 100 ether (100eth) to begin with.
Then I also changed my testrpc version to 4.1.3 and it worked! do : npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc@4.1.3
hope this will help!

Answer (score 2):

> testrpc -l 30000000

Did the trick for me.
-l will set a custom gas limit, in this case 30000000.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-testrpc

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc@4.1.3`

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I changed my version to 4.1.3 and it worked!
execute : npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc@4.1.3

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14515)